# How to apply a class to all button?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, forms, internet-explorer-6

In one of my projects I have used `input[type="button"]` to apply a style to all the buttons. It works fine in all browsers except Internet Explorer 6. It doesn't style the buttons.

Is there a solution for this, like creating some class for the button and applying it to all buttons?

I want to apply that class to all buttons but not manually. I think it's possible to use jQuery for this, could you please help me with this?

Comment: Can you give us an example what's wrong with IE. I suspect that this is probably some CSS not beign correctly interpreted on IE issue.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I usually like not to use JavaScript for this, so I add `class="text"` for `<input>` elements that are of text type, `class="button"` for `<input>` elements that are of button type, and so on. Then I can match them with `input.text` etc.

While you don't want to do it manually, I consider it better practice. If you still want to do it with jQuery, you do it like this:

```
$('input:button').addClass('button');
// Or to include <button> elements:
$('button, input:button').addClass('button');

// Text inputs:
$('input:text').addClass('text');
// And so on...
```

Answer (score 5):

```
$(":button").addClass("yourclassname");
```

This matches all button elements and input elements of type button and adds class to them.

Comment: `:button` means `*:button`. I would recommend changing it to `input:button`.

Comment: Then you're missing the <button> elements.

Comment: It won't select button elements.

Comment: But those are easy enough to match with CSS. I'd rather make the jQuery `$("button, input:button")` if I really wanted to add the class to all buttons. It would be more efficient than checking every single element on the page.

Comment: For the sake of argument, run this in Firebug on this page: `console.log($('input:text').length, '<', $('*').length);` I get `5 < 671` - so I think there ought to be some performance difference in specifying the element type. I'm surprised that jQuery doesn't add the possible element types to the query when they hit a `:text` etc selector, but according to the documentation (http://docs.jquery.com/Selectors/text), it doesn't. I haven't looked at the source though.

Comment: Sorry for the comment spam. I did have a look at the source now and `:something` filters are implemented in such a generic way, that it simply just runs whatever is after a colon through a `jQuery.expr.something` function, at a stage after the initial elements have already been selected, so it will select all elements.  But considering how often people use `:text` etc. instead of `input:text` I think it might be worth suggesting a special-case optimization...

Comment: @Blixt: very good point. Learned something new again today :) I checked the jQuery source also, and it suprised me how inefficient the :xxx filters have been implemented.

Answer (score 3):

have you tried `$(":button")` ?

Answer (score 2):

You can not do it automatically in IE6 without javascript. Here is how you can do it with jQuery

```
$(":button").addClass( "something" );
```

Answer (score 2):

I wouldn't use jQuery unless you need it elsewhere as loading a library or framework for such a simple task seems overkill.

I.E.6 doesn't understand CSS attribute selectors, correct, looks like Javascript is the only way.

Perhaps you could play with this code:

```
Buttons=Parent.getElementsByTagName("input"); // "Parent" could be "document" or the Id. of a form, fieldset, div etc.
Button=0;
while(Button<Buttons.length){
    if(Buttons[Button].getAttribute("type")=="button"){
        Buttons[Button].className="Whatever_Style_We_Want";
    }
    Button++;
};
```

I've not tried or tested that but the snippet is something to play with. It may even work right out of the box!

Answer (score 0):

This works to apply all styles to buttons in JavaScript

```
const buttons = document.getElementsByTagName('button');
    
    for(let i = 0; i < buttons.length; i++) {
        buttons[i].classList.add("my-button-class")
        buttons[i].classList.add("another-button-class")
    }
```